PMD Security - ApexSuggestNamedCredential Violation for Experian Integration on OAuth 2.0
We encountered a security issue flagged as "ApexSuggestNamedCredential" on various Experian-related integrations (such as Commercial Credit, Business Search, etc.).
To address this, we considered using the OAuth 2.0 mechanism via Salesforce Named Credentials. While Named Credentials allow storing the ClientId and ClientSecret, they don’t directly support storing the Username and Password. As a result, we explored the Custom Authentication Protocol in Named Credentials to retrieve an access token. However, using this approach still results in a PMD security violation because we must manually extract the access token from the third-party response and then use it to retrieve credit reports.
Issues Faced:
Using OAuth 2.0: If we could configure Named Credentials to use the full OAuth 2.0 flow, Salesforce would handle the access token securely and store it as an encrypted token, resolving the security issue flagged by PMD and Checkmarx. However, from Salesforce's response to our support ticket, it seems that Salesforce does not support storing all four required credentials (Username, Password, ClientId, and ClientSecret) using the OAuth 2.0 protocol in Named Credentials.
Experian Requirement: Experian’s documentation specifies that it is mandatory to pass Username, Password, ClientId, and ClientSecret in the headers or request body, which complicates the OAuth 2.0 implementation. Therefore, we’ve configured the integration using Custom Authentication Protocol, but this still leaves us with the manual access token extraction.
Security Violation:
When performing security scans (e.g., Checkmarx, PMD), we encountered the "ApexSuggestNamedCredentials" violation because of manually extracting access tokens from the Experian API response, which seems to be the core issue.
Request for Solutions:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution to bypass this security violation? Is there a secure way to integrate with Experian using Named Credentials while still adhering to their requirement of passing all credentials? Any guidance on how to resolve this without triggering PMD or Checkmarx violations would be greatly appreciated.
Here’s a sample of our current code for obtaining the access token and using it in the request:
public static final String USERNAME = '{!$Credential.Username}';
public static final String PASSWORD = '{!$Credential.Password}';
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_URL ='callout:Experian_US/oauth2/v1/token';
String authorizationToken = '';
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest reqForToken = new HttpRequest();
reqForToken.setMethod('POST');
reqForToken.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
reqForToken.setHeader('Client_id', clientId);
reqForToken.setHeader('Client_secret', clientSecret);
reqForToken.setEndpoint(AUTH_TOKEN_URL);
reqForToken.setBody(getTokenRequestBody());
private static String getTokenRequestBody() {
JSONGenerator tokenRequestBody = JSON.createGenerator(true);
tokenRequestBody.writeStartObject();
tokenRequestBody.writeStringField('username', USERNAME);
tokenRequestBody.writeStringField('password', PASSWORD);
tokenRequestBody.writeEndObject();
return tokenRequestBody.getAsString();
}
HttpResponse tokenResponse = http.send(reqForToken);
if (tokenResponse.getStatusCode() < 300) {
Map<String,Object> responseBody = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(tokenResponse.getBody());
if (responseBody.get('access_token') != null) {
authorizationToken = (String)responseBody.get('access_token');
}
}
try {
Http request = new Http();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authorizationToken);
HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(request);
} catch (Exception err) {
throw err;
}
How do we fix this Security violation for this scenario

sing OAuth 2.0: If we could configure Named Credentials to use the full OAuth 2.0 flow - Experian's token acquisition flow is a warped interpretation of password grant type in oAuth 2.0. This flow is outdated and insecure, it's removed from the upcoming revision (v2.1) of oAuth spec. Nevertheless, what you're trying to achieve is possible by using new Named + External Credentials. Use 'Custom Auth' +  interpolate multiple secrets (see example)
